# Chrome and Catalyst - no tab text

Tags: unity, drivers, google-chrome, fglrx

I just installed Ubuntu, updated, installed AMD proprietary drivers (for my Radeon HD6870) and noticed that some (most) of the tabs in Google Chrome don't have text, only the favicon.

My first idea was that maybe 13.10 may have some issues with the new drivers so I switched to the normal driver instead of the beta one. It was not good.

Okay then, I put back the open source drivers. It worked. Okay, it's strange. Let's install Ubuntu Gnome to see if it's Unity. No it was not.

Let's install Ubuntu 13.04. Same behavoir.

By this time I was desperate. I installed Fedora, the problem was there.

Now I'm back to Ubuntu 13.10, but am out of ideas.

Could anyone help me, please?

P.s.: I can upload a screenshot, if needed.

Comment: Same problem here. Experienced on multiple installs, in Unity, Gnome, and KDE.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You would probably be better off reporting it through the right channels.

Comment: Do you meaan Ubuntu 12.10, because as far as i know, Ubuntu 13.10 has not been released yet....at least for the next 16hours...??

Comment: Do you think it's really a problem with `Ubuntu` , `Fedora`, `your graphics card`, `AMD proprietary/Opensource drivers`? or `Google-Chrome`??

Answer (score 1):

The version of Catalyst that ships with Ubuntu 13.10 is outdated, version 13.8, and has a lot of general bugs and issues. With Radeon HD 6000 series, especially your Radeon HD 6870, it is more advisable to use the open source drivers instead of Catalyst. To get better open source drivers, add the oibaf ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Then reboot.

My Ubuntu 13.10 machines with Radeon HD 6850s all run perfectly with the default open source drivers, so I'm not sure why you want Catalyst. I'd only recommend Catalyst for Radeon HD 7000+ GPUs, but honestly I dislike how Canonical decided to make Catalyst 13.8 the default fglrx on Ubuntu 13.10's released instead of Catalyst 13.11 which has much needed RadeonSI fixes for HD 7000+ GPUs and support for their new R7 and R9 graphics cards.

Comment: Perhaps that will help when they are available.

Comment: Oibaf for Saucy became available ~30 hours ago.

Comment: Incidentally this did not solve the problem either. So I'm  guessing this could be a Chromium/Chrome bug with Radeon hardware, for some reason

Answer (score 1):

My radeon HD 6570 works well as well although I do notice some problems. However this is also a bug in Google Chrome and the latest Ubuntu. I suggest trying [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) the browser that google chrome is based off. If it works well then it's a google thing, If it has the same problem then try the solution above.

Comment: Tested.. unfortunately, the problem persists in the Open Source Chromium. This bug is also unique to Chrome/Chromium. I installed several other browsers that are webkit based, and have had no rendering issues of any kind. I'm going to take this over to the Chromium community.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue impacting both Chromium and Chrome. I changed the drivers couple times before, so I chose to do a cleanup and I removed the proprietary fglrx driver as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx)

All the scenarios in the instructions were applicable for me, so I executed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
```

rebooted and the text on tabs was back.